# Unable to open .Rproj with RStudio from terminal or ranger

Tags: command-line, bash, r, rstudio

I am trying to open an `.Rproj` file with RStudio from the terminal, or preferably with `ranger`. The default file opener in `ranger`, `rifle`, produces the following error when opening any `.Rproj` file:

```
E303: Unable to open swap file for "/path/to/file.Rproj" 13L, 205C
```

I've found limited resources opening an `.Rproj` file from terminal, but have tried the following:

```
open -a /path/to/file.Rproj
```

This returns:

```
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

Comment: (1) looks like you are trying to open a file in a directory to which you don't have write permission (or is mounted read-only) and (2) looks like you are running the system's [openvt command](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-openvt/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to open files from terminal using it's assigned default "open with" sofware.
In the console and asuming you are in the same place where your file lives, you must try:

xdg-open file.extension

I have opened several different kinds of files with "xdg-open", should be the same with *.Rproj.

Good luck!